# How to delete x number of entries with identical string and retain only one entry with modified header?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, fasta

I have a question for all you awk/sed/perl experts. I encountered a file that has the following format e.g.:

```
>GALHOMG00000016026_1 GALHOMT00000016026_1 GALHOMP00000016026_1 JH556633.1:35740-45316 1
MPKKKTGARKKAENRREREKQIRASRANIDLAKHPCNASMECDKCQRRQKNRAFCYFCNS
VQKLPICAQCGKTKCMMKSSDCVIKHAGVYSTGLAMVGAICDFCEAWVCHGRKCLSTHAC
TCPLADAECIECERSVWDHGGRIFACSFCHDFLCEDDQFEHQASCQVLEAETFKCVSCNR
LGQHSCLRCKACFCGDHVRSKVFKQEKGKEPPCPKCGHETQQTKDLSMSTRSLKFGRQTG
GEDADGASGYDAYWKNLSSSKPGDAGDREDEYDEYEAEDDDEDDNDEGGKDSDTETTDLF
SNLNLGRTYASGYAHYEEPED

>HUMHOMG00000262990_1 HUMHOMT00000262990_1 HUMHOMP00000262990_1 JH556633.1:35740-45316 1
MPKKKTGARKKAENRREREKQIRASRANIDLAKHPCNASMECDKCQRRQKNRAFCYFCNS
VQKLPICAQCGKTKCMMKSSDCVIKHAGVYSTGLAMVGAICDFCEAWVCHGRKCLSTHAC
TCPLADAECIECERSVWDHGGRIFACSFCHDFLCEDDQFEHQASCQVLEAETFKCVSCNR
LGQHSCLRCKACFCGDHVRSKVFKQEKGKEPPCPKCGHETQQTKDLSMSTRSLKFGRQTG
GEDADGASGYDAYWKNLSSSKPGDAGDREDEYDEYEAEDDDEDDNDEGGKDSDTETTDLF
SNLNLGRTYASGYAHYEEPED

>TGUHOMG00000002432_1 TGUHOMT00000002432_1 TGUHOMP00000002432_1 JH556633.1:35740-45316 1
MPKKKTGARKKAENRREREKQIRASRANIDLAKHPCNASMECDKCQRRQKNRAFCYFCNS
VQKLPICAQCGKTKCMMKSSDCVIKHAGVYSTGLAMVGAICDFCEAWVCHGRKCLSTHAC
TCPLADAECIECERSVWDHGGRIFACSFCHDFLCEDDQFEHQASCQVLEAETFKCVSCNR
LGQHSCLRCKACFCGDHVRSKVFKQEKGKEPPCPKCGHETQQTKDLSMSTRSLKFGRQTG
GEDADGASGYDAYWKNLSSSKPGDAGDREDEYDEYEAEDDDEDDNDEGGKDSDTETTDLF
SNLNLGRTYASGYAHYEEPED
```

I would like to modify this file into the following:

```
>JH556633.1:35740-45316
MPKKKTGARKKAENRREREKQIRASRANIDLAKHPCNASMECDKCQRRQKNRAFCYFCNS
VQKLPICAQCGKTKCMMKSSDCVIKHAGVYSTGLAMVGAICDFCEAWVCHGRKCLSTHAC
TCPLADAECIECERSVWDHGGRIFACSFCHDFLCEDDQFEHQASCQVLEAETFKCVSCNR
LGQHSCLRCKACFCGDHVRSKVFKQEKGKEPPCPKCGHETQQTKDLSMSTRSLKFGRQTG
GEDADGASGYDAYWKNLSSSKPGDAGDREDEYDEYEAEDDDEDDNDEGGKDSDTETTDLF
SNLNLGRTYASGYAHYEEPED
```

I know that I can modify what I call the header (I mean the line following the >) like this:

```
awk 'NF > 1{$0=">"$4}; {print $0}' file.fa > file2.fa
```

My question is, how do I delete the two other paragraphs? It is possible that there are instances in the file in which the sequence of characters of the paragraphs (ie not counting the header line) is not identical. In that case, I would like to append an extension based on the number of entries with the same identifier (for example in this case `JH556633.1-1:35740-45316` for the first `JH556633.1-2:35740-45316` for the second, or something similar). The point is to make the identical headers (the row that starts with `>`) different but keep the original sequence of character if they are not identical.

If anyone has an idea to solve this I would greatly appreciate the assistance. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the row after the one with `greater than sign` or the row that starts with `greater than sign`?

Comment: Please show us your attempts to solve the problem (not just the awk command you've posted, which only deals with the first line).

Comment: Thanks for the constructive replies! Alien kindly fly off to your planet with your spaceship

Comment: I meant the row that starts with greater than sign mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. It does not depend on empty lines between the different sequences since not all fasta files will have those. It adds `_N` to each ID where `N` is the number of times that ID has been found. IDs that have only been associated with a single sequence will have `_1`. If an ID is associated with multiple, different sequences, all such sequences will be printed.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

## The field of the ID line you want to keep.
## Since we start counting from 0, to get the 4th
## field, set this to 3.
my $want=3;

my (@fields,%seqs,%seen,$seq);
## Read the input file
while (<>) {
    ## Skip blank lines
    next if /^\s*$/;
    ## remove trailing newlines
    chomp;
    ## Is this an ID line?
    if (/^\s*>(.*)/) {
        ## Save the previous sequence (if any). The %seqs 
        ## hash has the sequence as a key and the desired 
        ## ID as a value.
        if ($fields[0]) {
            $seqs{$seq}=$fields[$want];                 
            ## Clear the previous sequence and IDs
            $seq="";
            @fields=();
        }
        ## Split the ID fields into @fields.
        @fields=split(/\s+/);
    }
    ## If this is a sequence, add to $seq
    else {
        $seq.=$_;
    }
}
## Get the last sequence
$seqs{$seq}=$fields[$want];                 

foreach my $sequence (sort keys(%seqs)) {
    ## Add an identifier.
    $seen{$seqs{$sequence}}++;
    print ">$seqs{$sequence}_$seen{$seqs{$sequence}}\n";
    ## Convert the sequence back to FASTA
    $sequence=~s/(.{60})/$1\n/g;
    print "$sequence\n";
}
```

Save the script as `foo.pl` or whatever, make it executable `chmod 744 foo.pl` and run as:

```
$ ./foo.pl file.fa 
>JH556633.1:35740-45316_1
MPKKKTGARKKAENRREREKQIRASRANIDLAKHPCNASMECDKCQRRQKNRAFCYFCNS
VQKLPICAQCGKTKCMMKSSDCVIKHAGVYSTGLAMVGAICDFCEAWVCHGRKCLSTHAC
TCPLADAECIECERSVWDHGGRIFACSFCHDFLCEDDQFEHQASCQVLEAETFKCVSCNR
LGQHSCLRCKACFCGDHVRSKVFKQEKGKEPPCPKCGHETQQTKDLSMSTRSLKFGRQTG
GEDADGASGYDAYWKNLSSSKPGDAGDREDEYDEYEAEDDDEDDNDEGGKDSDTETTDLF
SNLNLGRTYASGYAHYEEPED
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$4` can't contain `&` or `\<digit>` per your posted input (if it can it's a trivial tweak):

```
$ awk -v RS= '!seen[$4]++{sub(/[^\n]+/,$4);print}' file
JH556633.1:35740-45316
MPKKKTGARKKAENRREREKQIRASRANIDLAKHPCNASMECDKCQRRQKNRAFCYFCNS
VQKLPICAQCGKTKCMMKSSDCVIKHAGVYSTGLAMVGAICDFCEAWVCHGRKCLSTHAC
TCPLADAECIECERSVWDHGGRIFACSFCHDFLCEDDQFEHQASCQVLEAETFKCVSCNR
LGQHSCLRCKACFCGDHVRSKVFKQEKGKEPPCPKCGHETQQTKDLSMSTRSLKFGRQTG
GEDADGASGYDAYWKNLSSSKPGDAGDREDEYDEYEAEDDDEDDNDEGGKDSDTETTDLF
SNLNLGRTYASGYAHYEEPED
```

It looks like you have another question too so post a new question with some representative input and expected output for that question.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/^>\([^ ]\{1,\} \)\{3\}/>/;/^ *$/q;p' YourFile
```

based on your sample (posix version so `--posix`on GNU sed)